# V-for is not iterating through objects

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of coupon objects named **offers**:

```
 [{ "coupon": 
             { "id": "1", "name": "Coupon 1" } 
  }, 
  { "coupon": 
             { "id": "2", "name": "Coupon 2" } 
  }]
```

And i try to iterate trough it like this:

```
<div v-for="(coupon, $index) in offers" :key="$index">
     <p>{{coupon.id}}</p>
</div>
```

The problem is that div does not iterate anything.

Comment: try `coupon.coupon.id` since coupon is a key in offers

Comment: @depperm The problem is not that i dont see coupon id. The problem is that array is not iterating. I have tried like this:

`<div v-for="(coupon, $index) in offers" :key="$index">`
     `<p>Test</p>`
`</div>`

Which doesn't work as well.

Comment: Why does index have $?

Comment: Well but it should So either your offers array does not actually have data or the script fails somewhere else. Check the console to look for errors, and use `Vue devtools` in your browser to check if the variable actually exists. You can also print it outside the v-for to check the contents by just doing `<div>{{ offers }}</div>`

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/or3c69Lk/) showing it does iterate. You may have some other error that is stopping it though

Comment: I have printed result in my component when setting data and there i can see that data is there.

Comment: how about you provide more of your code, as it is posted currently the iteration does happen you just need to see my first comment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n09hsL3j/

Answer (score 0):

you have to travel through the object, the First coupon is an element name so try this. This should work

```
div v-for="(coupon, $index) in offers" :key="$index">
    <p>{{coupon.coupon.id}}</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div v-for="{ coupon } in offers" :key="coupon.id">
   <p>{{ coupon.name }}</p>
</div>
```

Dont use index as key

Comment: Why i need to use v-for="{ coupon } in offers" instead of v-for="coupon in offers"?

Comment: Because your array items are objects with key `coupon` in it.
Suggested you to use `{ coupon } in offers` based on object destructuring https://dev.to/sarah_chima/object-destructuring-in-es6-3fm

Comment: Didn't work. I think the problem here is that this is done in .jsp file and not .html